# Xcode Swift 4 Facebook & Twitter sharing no longer working?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, twitter

i am using Facebook & Twitter sharing in my app , after upgrade xCode to 9.0.1 Swift 4, both are not working , the method saying i have no FB or Tw account on my device but they're already there and was working fine with Swift 3.

Log :

```
2017-10-25 09:53:41.619676+0300 jack[2428:926750] [core] isAvailableForServiceType: for com.apple.social.facebook returning NO
```

and here is the Code :

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            {

                let shareText = "xxx"

                let facebookShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
                    //facebookShare.add(imageView.image!)
                    facebookShare.add(URL(string:self.track.share_url))
                    facebookShare.setInitialText(shareText)

                self.present(facebookShare, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
            {
                let shareText = "xxx"
                let twitterSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
                    twitterSheet.add(URL(string : self.track.share_url))
                    twitterSheet.setInitialText( shareText )

                self.present(twitterSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Those have been disabled with iOS 11. You should no longer see the Facebook NOR twitter sub-menus in the iOS Settings app.

I would suggest you to use the regular sharing options or the fb/twitter APIs.

Vincent

Answer (score 1):

Dont check if its available anymore; isAvailable(forServiceType:), just run it direct. I faced similar issue myself

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Facebook's SDK to share: FBSDKShareKit

You can install it using cocoa pods:

```
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

Example

```
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

-(IBAction)sharingOnFacebook:(id)sender {
     FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
     content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myPageWeb/"];

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
}
```

And for Twitter the steps are similar: TwitterKit

```
pod 'TwitterKit'
```

Example:

```
-(IBAction)sharingOnTwitter:(id)sender {
    TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
    [composer setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://https://myPageWeb/"]];
    [composer showFromViewController:self completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
        /*if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
        }*/
    }];
}
```

NOTE: Read Facebook and Twitter documentation because you need to do some steps for your app previously. Register the app, get the AppID...

[Facebook iOS Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

[Twitter iOS Developers page](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation)

Comment: The code for Swift is in the documentation of Facebook or Twitter

Comment: Hey Saul, sorry if this is a stupid question but for me, SLComposeViewController works perfectly fine in my code with iOS 12, although Xcode notifies me it is deprecated. Even though it is bad practice to use deprecated code, could I still publish my app with SLComposeViewController? Or would Apple reject it?

Comment: Of course you can publish it, Apple should not reject app for this reason. But in a future I would be great that you update your code :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Saul

Comment: Twitter will be discontinuing support for Twitter Kit on October 31, 2018.https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html